# MOD rewrite all URLS after some specific URL folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, web

I need to redirect all requests with this particular string in their URL address :  "domain.com/subfolder1/" to the new location "subdomain.domain.com"
Any ideas how to do that?

I tried : 
RewriteRule   "^domain.com/subfolder1/(.*)"  "http://subdomain.domain.com/$1"  [R,L=301] 
but no luck

thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

A Redirect will be enough. In the virtualhost for example.com you can define:

```
Redirect permanent /subdirectory1/ http://subdomain.example.com/
```

If you don't want the original request end in the destination just use:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^ http://subdomain.example.com/
```

Comment: Thanks, it sort of worked, but to make it more complicated : The old URLs are not on the new location so basicaly I need anything with this partial string in URL, to be redirected to fixed URL :subdomain.domain.com....no URL after that. Any idea?

Comment: Note that I said "In virtualhost example.com" you can define. That is, have a virtualhost for the old domain where you should define this.

Comment: Sorry I am not that good I guess, I just have ftp from my provider, where all my files sit. There I have htaccess, which I have not large knowledge of. I entered the lines you wrote into this Htaccess,and it worked OK, except a fact which I need to solve now : domain.com/subfolder1/ANYTHING.php to be redirected to subdomain.domain.com ....note that I DONT want this new redirected URL to contain ANY page.php or anything like that....

Comment: @Jozef There, I added a new redirect in my answer, so the original request does not end at target, it just gets redirected to the new hostname.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I tried both of your codelines to place in htaccess, unfortunately both of them /any of them results in error. Is it only part of the command (do I have to add something specific before that/after that code) or it is complete code including all specific commands?